# Seam 2.3 + JSF + AJAX. When re-rendering one panel methods in other panel get called too

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jboss-seam

my project is built using JBoss Seam 2.3, JSF 2.1 and richfaces. There's something I don't fully understand when re-rendering components using richfaces aj4 calls.

When some action is executed using a4j and the value of the render attribute points to some h:panelGroup id, methods in other panel are called too.

I prepared some code to demonstrate this.

BeanA.java. Simulates data access.

```
package test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.jboss.seam.ScopeType;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.Logger;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.Name;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.Scope;
import org.jboss.seam.log.Log;

@Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
@Name("beanA")
public class BeanA {

    @Logger
    private Log log;

    public List<Integer> list() {
        log.info("beanA.list()");
        // DB Query simulation
        Integer[] result = {1,2,3};
        return Arrays.asList(result);
    }

}
```

BeanB.java. Simple clicks counter.

```
package test;

import org.jboss.seam.ScopeType;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.Logger;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.Name;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.Scope;
import org.jboss.seam.log.Log;

@Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
@Name("beanB")
public class BeanB {

    @Logger
    private Log log;

    private int counter = 0;

    public void dumbAction() {
        // do nothing
        log.info("beanB.dumbAction()");
        counter++;
    }

    public int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }

    public void setCounter(int counter) {
        this.counter = counter;
    }

}
```

test.xhtml

```
<f:view xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:a="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:richext="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/richext"
    xmlns:s="http://jboss.org/schema/seam/taglib" contentType="text/html"
        xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
    <h:html>
    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>TEST</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

        <h:panelGroup id="listPanel">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <h:outputText value="a:repeat" />
                </li>
                <a:repeat value="#{beanA.list()}" var="i">
                    <li>
                        <h:outputText value="#{i}" />
                    </li>
                </a:repeat>
            </ul>
<!--            <ul> -->
<!--                <li> -->
<!--                    <h:outputText value="ui:repeat" /> -->
<!--                </li> -->
<!--                <ui:repeat value="#{beanA.list()}" var="i"> -->
<!--                    <li> -->
<!--                        <h:outputText value="#{i}" /> -->
<!--                    </li> -->
<!--                </ui:repeat> -->
<!--            </ul> -->
<!--            <ul> -->
<!--                <li> -->
<!--                    <h:outputText value="c:foreach" /> -->
<!--                </li> -->
<!--                <c:forEach items="#{beanA.list()}" var="i"> -->
<!--                    <li> -->
<!--                        <h:outputText value="#{i}" /> -->
<!--                    </li> -->
<!--                </c:forEach> -->
<!--            </ul> -->
        </h:panelGroup>

        <h:form>
            <a:commandLink value="Dumb action" action="#{beanB.dumbAction()}"
                execute="@this" render="timesDumbActionPanel" />
        </h:form>

        <h:panelGroup id="timesDumbActionPanel">
            <h:outputText value="#{beanB.counter}" />
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:body>
    </h:html>
</f:view>
```

When I load the page /test.seam beanA.list() is called once. When I click "Dumb action" link the following is logged:

```
19:28:21,461 INFO  [test.BeanA] (http--0.0.0.0-80-1) beanA.list()
19:28:21,461 INFO  [test.BeanB] (http--0.0.0.0-80-1) beanB.dumbAction()
19:28:21,461 INFO  [test.BeanA] (http--0.0.0.0-80-1) beanA.list()
```

beanA.list() is called twice and I don't understand why. When using ui:repeat instead of a:repeat beanA.list() is called like 11 times. I also tried to change scopes but the results were the same.

**The behaviour I expect is just call beanB.dumbAction() and re-render the panel to refresh counter.**

I do know getters are called multiple times, but does this apply to all methods too?

What I do to avoid this is just create a field for the list and modify the getter to initialize it if it's not. Something like this:

```
@Name("beanA")
public class BeanA {

    @Logger
    private Log log;

    private List<Integer> list;

    public void initList() {
        log.info("beanA.list()");
        // DB Query simulation
        Integer[] result = { 1, 2, 3 };
        setList(Arrays.asList(result));
    }

    public List<Integer> getList() {
        if (list == null)
            initList();
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<Integer> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

}
```

The getter is still called but not initList() which is just OK. This way I avoid executing queries more than necessary. The only problem is when data changes. I need to manually call initList() again and it's not enough with just re-rendering it's panel.

Maybe I'm missing something with JSF lifecycle or something, could you please give me some hint on this? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I do know getters are called multiple times, but does this apply to all methods too?

It's not like JSF knows that a specific method is a getter. If you're using in a place that asks for data, e.g. @value then it's a getter.

The reason you're seeing multiple calls to getters is because when JSF/RichFaces is looking for a certain element it has to go through all the elements before it. In your case in order to find `timesDumbActionPanel` it has to go through `listPanel` and check inside the `a4j:repeat`.

> The only problem is when data changes. I need to manually call initList() again and it's not enough with just re-rendering it's panel.

You can call `initList()` from whatever method is changing the data.